# How do i fetch data from database to wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created a educational website in which students are registered with unique id till now there is no problem but i want to show thier some info from my database with particular unique id.I have created website in wordpress.Please Help me

Comment: You can use PHP, or MySQL from the command line. Once you've tried, show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: How i can started with  it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    WordPress Database Functions

    Following are some basic methods

    /**
    * insert
    */
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $mytitle ) );

    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->options, array(
            'option_name',
            'new_option_key',
            'option_value' => 'New Option Value',
            'autoload' => 'yes' )
            );

    /**
    * update
    */
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $mytitle ),
            array( 'ID' => $myid )
            );

    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options,
            array( 'option_value' => 'New Option Value' ),
            array( 'option_name' => 'new_option_value' )
            );

    /**
    * get_var
    */
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM
                    $wpdb->postmeta WHERE
                    post_id = %d AND
                    meta_key = 'enclosure' AND
                    meta_value LIKE (%s)", $post_ID, $url . '&' )
            );

    $content = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM " .
                    "$wpdb->posts WHERE " .
                    "post_title = %s AND " .
                    "ID = %d", $title, $id )
        );

    /**
    * query
    */
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = '$name'" );

    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_title = '$mytitle' WHERE ID = $myid" );

    /**
    * query and escape
    */
    $mytitle = $wpdb->escape( $mytitle );
    $myid    = absint( $myid );
    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_title = '$mytitle' WHERE ID = $myid" );

    /**
    * get_results
    */
    $type = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_type FROM " .
                "$wpdb->posts WHERE ID=$id" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL 
   query statement that returns a PHP object

   global $wpdb;
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );

  // 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require 
   global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

  $results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```